# Using a multilayered dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures

Sorry if I'm not using the right terminology in my question but I'm hoping this will clear it up.

Basically I have the following data structure:

Match_id as top key
players and winning_team contained as keys within
list of players and boolean value for values of players and winning_team.

```
{"match_id":[{"players": [list], "winning_team": True}]}
```

Right now I'm storing this using two dictionaries, under this structure:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>
```

However this requires two dictionaries, and I have a lot of matches to evaluate iteratively. I want to know if I can store a dictionary with this format without creating a new dictionary.

Comment: It looks like JSON, why not have a real class and desearalize it correctly?

Comment: I used JSON just to show the structure, as I couldn't get a decent graphical layout using the site editor,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a class:

```
public MyClass 
{
   public List<string> Players{get;set;}
   public bool WinningTeam {get;set;}
}
```

And initialize your dictionary like this:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
```

And you can add like:

```
myDictionary.Add("match_id", new MyClass()
{ 
   Players: new List<string>(), 
   WinningTeam:true
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In terms of large data storage will this be significantly more efficient?

Comment: Yes. It'll be efficient